# Unable to subscribe to rich notifications in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

How can I create a subscription with rich notifications in MS Graph?

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

```
{
    "resource": "users/{email}/messages?$select=hasAttachments",
    "changeType": "created",
    "clientState": "415e99b4-73af-454e-93b5-00eb6c3082b9",
    "notificationUrl": "https://229c8207.ngrok.io/Notification/Listen",
    "includeProperties": true,
    "expirationDateTime": "2019-01-16T22:21:56.3942423+00:00"
}
```

Expected: 202 Created

Actual: 400 Bad Request

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Microsoft.Exchange workload is not enabled for rich notifications.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7e03b3c9-aa49-4222-b7a7-5fddebc82327",
            "date": "2019-01-16T16:47:24"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with the beta api?  replaced "v1.0" with "beta" in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rich notifications" are not yet enabled through Microsoft Graph. We are working on it and will be adding some exciting new capabilities. We cannot provide an ETA at this time, but it is top of our list for this feature area.

Comment: 33 months later, I wonder if it's still at the top of the list...

Comment: I believe this worked in the old API too